# What is a good jQuery timePicker?

Tags: jquery

What is a good jQuery timePicker?

Comment: one that works and suits your task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [jQuery.timepickr](http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/).

Answer (score 1):

http://jonthornton.github.com/jquery-timepicker/

This is a pretty clean and Efficient Jquery Timepicker .

Answer (score 1):

[Bootstrap Timepicker](http://jdewit.github.com/bootstrap-timepicker/) is also simple and clean if you are using jQuery with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/j-mcnally/kohTimePicker

this one is one i whiped together for a very simple timepicker interface.